# asignar a una variable un arreglo

Tags: php, web, variables

tengo el siguiente problema ojala me puedan ayudar tengo una pagina que me mostrara unas calificaciones del usuario que inicio sesión, pero creo que estoy asignando mal la variable a una variable de sesión es decir $boleta=$_SESSION, no se si me explico no se como asignarle a mi variable el contenido de mi variable de sesión, ya tengo cargadas las calificaciones en mi bd, el caso es que cuando intento cargar la pagina me imprime la tabla pero no su contenido es decir lo que estoy consultando no aparece y yo creo que es por que no estoy asignando bien un valor a mi variable o no estoy haciendo bien mi consulta alguien que me diga como puedo corregirlo???gracias :)
les dejo mi codigo:

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['Usuario'];
include "conexion.php";
?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<head>
<link href="csscali.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calificaciones</title>
<link href="csscali" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/estilos.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"  href="./js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<center><h1>CALIFICACIONES</h1></center>
   <?php mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
   mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); ?>


  <table border="0px" width="100%"> 
    <tr>

      <td>Materia</td>
      <td>Calificación 1</td>
      <td>Calificación 2</td>
      <td>Calificación 3</td>
      <td>Calificación Final</td>
      <td>Asistencia 1</td>
      <td>Asistencia 2</td>
      <td>Asistencia 3</td>
    </tr> 
<?php
      $re=mysql_query("select * from boleta where CURP" );
    $boleta=$_SESSION['Usuario'];

      while ($f=mysql_fetch_array($re)) {
          if($boleta!=$f['boleta']){
            echo '<tr><td>alumno: '.$f['CURP'].' </td></tr>';
          }
          $reportes=$f['reportes'];
          echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$f['MATERIA'].'</td>
            <td>'.$f['CALIFICCION1'].'</td>
              <td>'.$f['CALIFICCION2'].'</td>
              <td>'.$f['CALIFICCION3'].'</td>
              <td>'.$f['CALIFICCION_FINAL'].'</td>
              <td>'.$f['ASISTENCIA1'].'</td>
              <td>'.$f['ASISTENCIA2'].'</td>
              <td>'.$f['ASISTENCIA3'].'</td>
          </tr>';
      }
    ?>

  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buenas, ¿te valió la respuesta?

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que estas definiendo la variable `$_SESSION['Usuario']` pero no le estas dando valor, y luego estas igualando la variable `$boleta` a esa variable y por tanto ambas quedan vacías.

Revisa el funcionamiento de las variables de sesión para que puedas ver como debes usarlas.

http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php